# Linked list keeps getting unhandled exception

Tags: c#

I keep getting an unhandled exception

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

for the following code, specifically on the line `temp.next = node`. Can anyone help me figure out why?

The code below is a class for birds where the user inputs a name and the `addBird` method is suppose to add the name to the end of the linked list.

```
 class BirdsSurve    {

    private Node first;

    public class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public  int count { get; set; }
        public Node next;

        public Node()
        {


            this.count = 1;


        }

        public void setNext(Node Next)
        {

            next = Next;

        }
        public int addCount()
        {
             count++;
            return count;
        }
    }
    public BirdsSurvey()
    {
        this.first = null;

    }
    public void addBird(string bird)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.Name = bird;
        if (first == null)
        { first = node; }
        else
        {
           Node temp = first;
            while (temp != null)
            {
                if (temp.Name == bird)
                { temp.addCount(); }


                if (temp.next == null)
                {
                    temp = temp.next;
                    temp.next = node; }
               // temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `if (temp.next == null)` -> if temp.next **IS** null, `temp = temp.next;` set temp to temp's next (i.e. set temp to `null`), and then `temp.next = node;` try to access a property of the `null` value.

Comment: Comment out `temp = temp.next;` It should not be there.

Comment: `I tried setting the setting temp to null` **No-one** suggested you do that. Have another read of my earlier suggestion.

Comment: @Ace consider `temp = null; temp.next = node;` - how can you access `.next` if `temp` is null?

Answer (score 2):

You set `temp` to `temp.next` within the `if` clause, which checks, if `temp.next` is `null`. So, you basically set `temp` to be `null`. So, you get the error, because you try to get a `next` property from a variable, which is `null` and not an object.

As a side note, maybe rethink the naming of your variables, so that they are not all the same, because that can become confusing quite fast.